# convert decimal to string python

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, tostring

I imported tab delimited file to create a dataframe (`df`) which has the following `label`:

```
label
1
2

3

1
```

This is stored as pandas.core.series.Series and I want to convert it to string format so that I can get rid of the decimals when I write this out to a text file.

```
df.class_label=df.label.fillna('')
df.to_string(columns=['label'],index=False)
```

The variable type is still `Series`, and output (text file) also has the decimals:

```
1.0 2.0  3.0  1.0
```

How to get rid of these decimals?

Comment: How are you exporting this to a text file or csv?

Comment: Using `pd.read_csv(file,sep='\t')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `float_format` keyword argument of the `to_string()` method:

```
df.to_string(columns=['label'], index=False, float_format=lambda x: '{:d}'.format(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `astype(int)` will change a `float` to an `int` and will drop your `.0` as desired.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'label': [1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0]})
print(df)

    label
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   4.0
3   1.0

df.label = df.label.astype(int)
print(df)

    label
0   1
1   2
2   4
3   1
```

Here we do not need to convert this to a string. This will be done when exporting to `.csv` or `.txt` and will preserve the `int`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some `NaN` values, so `int` are converted to `float` because [na type promotions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions).

So you can read data in column `label` as `str` and then it works nice:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

temp=u"""lab1;label
5;1
5;2
7;
7;3
"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=';', dtype={'label':str})
print (df)
  lab1 label
0    5     1
1    5     2
2    7   NaN
3    7     3

df['class_label'] = df.label.fillna('')
print (df)
  lab1 label class_label
0    5     1           1
1    5     2           2
2    7   NaN            
3    7     3           3

print (df.to_string(columns=['class_label'],index=False))
class_label
         1
         2

         3
```